# cite in caption of listings

Tags: listings, captions, citing

I am trying to cite a paper in the caption of listings. I have the following code:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example of something (Adapted from \cite{abc})]
   example
\end{lstlisting}
```

But this is giving me error! It says `! Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a`. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try `\protect\cite{abc}`?

Comment: I've added an answer, but please add a minimal example to your question, so that we can get a better insight into the issue.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems a typical "fragile command in a moving argument problem". However the following document doesn't show any problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Example of something (Adapted from \cite{abc})]
   example
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{abc} x
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

So I suspect that you're using some package that kill the robustness of `\cite` in some way.

A way to solve the issue is writing

```
\protect\cite{abc}
```

in the caption, but probably it can be better addressed with a minimal example available.

As correctly remarks Gonzalo Medina in his comment, there's also the possibility of writing

```
\begin{lstlisting}[
  caption={[Example of something]Example of something (Adapted from \cite{abc})}
]
```

so that only "Example of something" will be sent to the list of listings (which is very important if the adopted bibliography style is "unsorted").