# How to use citation in a figure

Tags: floats, citing

Goal: Use \cit{...} e.g. in a circle or box, etc., when drawing a figure. And then include this figure and compile it with pdflatex.

With Xfig, we can do similar things with math mode, but how to do it with cite?

Is there another tool supporting cite in bibtex style?

(Please note: This question is about to cite a paper within a figure, NOT about using label and ref to cite the figure. Nor do I mean to cite in the figure caption.)

Thanks!

Comment: This is a common problem as the (moving) argument of `\caption` contains a fragile command - `\cite` in this case. Use `\protect\cite`. See [`\cite` in caption `beamer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69162/5764) or [`\cite` in caption of `listings`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60337/5764). Also, as reference, see [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764)

Comment: Do you include an export from Xfig to "combined ps/LaTeX (both parts)"? If so, then you should be able to use the traditional `\label`-`\ref` system to reference a figure.

Comment: No, it is no problem for me to reference a figure. The goal is to cite !within! a figure. Thanks.

Comment: I might just be thick, but this makes no sense. I think it's best if you describe, in more detail (hopefully by providing a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)) how you create your image/figure. `\cite` can be used anywhere in a document, even in a figure. In moving arguments you use `\protect\cite`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you can use math in `xfig`, you already have the solution, just use `\cite` in math. Stuff that does not like math mode can be wrapped in `\mbox`:

```
$\mbox{Whatever}$
```

**Example for xfig**

Xfig file `cite.fig`:

```
#FIG 3.2  Produced by xfig version 3.2.5b
Landscape
Center
Metric
A4      
100.00
Single
-2
1200 2
2 4 0 1 0 7 50 -1 -1 0.000 0 0 7 0 0 5
         2565 2025 2565 1710 2160 1710 2160 2025 2565 2025
4 0 0 50 -1 0 12 0.0000 6 165 1080 2250 1935 $\\cite{foo}$\001
```

And the LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\input{cite.pdf_t}
\end{figure}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{abc}John Doe, \textit{The Alphabet}, 2000.
\bibitem{foo}N.\,N., \textit{The Mysteries of Foobar}, 1970.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is an `Asymptote` example of cited references with `hyperref` links, `c.tex`,
with attached `texbooks.bib` file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{texbooks.bib}
@Book{TeXbook,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {The TeXbook},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1986},
  address = {Reading, Mass},
  isbn = {0201134470}
}
@Book{MFbook,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {The METAFONTbook},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1986},
  address = {Reading, Mass},
  isbn = {0201134454}
}
@Book{Goossens:1994,
  author = {Goossens, Michel},
  title = {The LaTeX companion},
  publisher = {Addison},
  year = {1994},
  address = {Reading, Mass},
  isbn = {0201541998}
}
@Book{Karow:1994font,
  author = {Karow, Peter},
  title = {Font technology : methods and tools},
  publisher = {Springer-Verlag},
  year = {1994},
  address = {Berlin New York},
  isbn = {3540572236}
}
@Book{Knuth:1999digital,
  author = {Knuth, Donald},
  title = {Digital typography},
  publisher = {CSLI Publications},
  year = {1999},
  address = {Stanford, Calif},
  isbn = {1575860104}
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=DarkBlue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(300);
string[] citeName={
"MFbook",
"TeXbook",
"Goossens:1994",
"Karow:1994font",
"Knuth:1999digital"
};

pen p=orange+1.3pt;
real w=90;
draw(Label("\hbox to "+string(w)+"pt{\cite{"+citeName[0]+"}}",(-3w,w)),ellipse,p);
draw(Label("\hbox to "+string(w)+"pt{\cite{"+citeName[1]+"}}",(0,0)),ellipse,p);
draw(Label("\hbox to "+string(w)+"pt{\cite{"+citeName[2]+"}}",(3w,w)),roundbox,p);
draw(Label("\hbox to "+string(w)+"pt{\cite{"+citeName[3]+"}}",(-3w,-w)),ellipse,p);
draw(Label("\hbox to "+string(w)+"pt{\cite{"+citeName[4]+"}}",(3w,-w)),roundbox,p);

\end{asy}
\caption{Some citations in a figure. Inline \texttt{Asymptote} example.}
\end{figure}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{texbooks}

\end{document}
```

To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:

```
sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

and run `latexmk -pdf c.tex`.

Comment: awesome! didnt know about asymptote. Thanks!